# Python rename KML file name wit '(' and ')'

Tags: python

I am trying to rename a few KML files with 
1) spaces to _ 
2) - to _

I am running the script in Arcmap. for the first two it works fine.

But for the ( and ) it's going wrong ?

```
# Rename file
path = "C:\\DATA\\"
files = os.listdir(path)

for file in files:
  os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, file.replace("-", "_")))

for file in files:
  os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, file.replace(" ", "_")))

for file in files:
  os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, file.replace("(", "_")))

for file in files:
  os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, file.replace(")", "_")))
```

The goals is that I need to import KML files, import them in a Gdb, and then Append them to a excisting layer.

The whole script already works. But I still need to rename the files manually while the gdb will not take in files wit a - minus blancs and ( or ) sign whom are by default in a lot of kml files I have.

Below the whole script that works fine, if i manually rename the - or ( or ) or blanks

```
# Name: BatchKML_to_GDB.py
# Description: Converts a directory of KMLs and copies the output into a single fGDB.
#              A 2 step process: first convert the KML files, and then copy the featureclases

# Import system models
import arcpy, os

# Rename file
path = "C:\\DATA\\"
files = os.listdir(path)

for file in files:
  os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, file.replace(" ", "_")))

for file in files:
  os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, file.replace("-", "_")))

# Set workspace (where all the KMLs are)
arcpy.env.workspace= (r"C:\DATA")

# Set local variables and location for the consolidated file geodatabase
outLocation = "C:\\WorkingData\\fGDBs"
MasterGDB = 'AllKMLLayers.gdb'
MasterGDBLocation = os.path.join(outLocation, MasterGDB)

# Create the master FileGeodatabase
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(outLocation, MasterGDB)

# Convert all KMZ and KML files found in the current workspace
for kml in arcpy.ListFiles('*.kml'):
  print "CONVERTING: " + os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace,kml)
  arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion(kml, outLocation)


# Change the workspace to fGDB location
arcpy.env.workspace = outLocation

# Loop through all the FileGeodatabases within the workspace
wks = arcpy.ListWorkspaces('*', 'FileGDB')
# Skip the Master GDB
wks.remove(MasterGDBLocation)

for fgdb in wks:  

  # Change the workspace to the current FileGeodatabase
  arcpy.env.workspace = fgdb    

  # For every Featureclass inside, copy it to the Master and use the name from the original fGDB  
  featureClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*', '', 'Placemarks')
  for fc in featureClasses:
    print "COPYING: " + fc + " FROM: " + fgdb    
    fcCopy = fgdb + os.sep + 'Placemarks' + os.sep + fc    
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fcCopy, MasterGDBLocation, fgdb[fgdb.rfind(os.sep)+1:-4])


# Clean up
del kml, wks, fc, featureClasses, fgdb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be obvious why this doesn't work - once one of your loops has actually renamed a file, the subsequent loops won't be able to find it, because they're still looking for the original name!

You need a SINGLE loop, with all of the `.replace()` operations chained together so that the file gets renamed directly to its final name.

Comment: can you give me a tip/example? That would really help

Comment: `file.replace("-", "_").replace(" ", "_").replace("(", "_").replace(")", "_")`

Comment: great really helped